# Is it possible to create a recursive data type with rational numbers like -> data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat?

Tags: haskell, recursion

Is it possible to create a recursive data for rational numbers?
I saw this one for natural numbers

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

I probably need to use two numbers for the ratio? But something like Zero,Zero doesnt work.

Thanks!

Comment: You can define a `data Nat0 = One | Succ0 Nat0`, all natural numbers except zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Positive rational numbers

We can define it like:

```
data Nat0 = One | Succ0 Nat0
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
data PosRational = PosRational Nat Nat0
```

so here we use two data types `Nat0` (**excluding** zero), and `Nat` (including zero) that are defined recursively, and a data type `PosRational` that takes a `Nat` and `Nat0` (so a numerator, and a denominator).

## Including negative rational numbers

We can also include negative rational numbers, for instance by defining:

```
data Z = Pos Nat | Neg Nat0
```

and then define our `Rational` as:

```
data Rational = Rational Z Nat0
```

## Countability of ℚ

Nevertheless we actually do not need that (given we do not need fast access to the numerator and denominator). **Rational numbers are countable**. We can enumerate all of them with the following scheme [[source]](https://www.homeschoolmath.net/teaching/rational-numbers-countable.php):

[image: countability of rational numbers]

So we can simply define it as:

```
data Rational = Zero | NextRational Rational
```

Basically, every countable set can use this definition, so ℕ, ℤ, ℙ, ℚ, etc.

Comment: I wouldn't quite call this type `Rational`, since it does not include the negative numbers, but it's worth the trade-off to not have to first define the integers in terms of natural numbers.

Comment: @chepner: good point, I updated it with a possible way to represent negative rational numbers, although we can of course do it at the `Rational` level as well.

Comment: Just for fun: a *much* better way to define `Z` is `data Z = Nat :- Nat`, together with a quotienting rule `instance Eq Z where (a :- b) == (c :- d) = (a + d) == (c + b)`. This significantly reduces the headaches involved with defining the usual arithmetic operations, as there is generally just one case rather than four to consider.

Comment: For (much less) fun: define an addition function for rationals represented by `Zero | NextRational Rational` :)